# Covariance of ARMA(2,1) series

Tags: time-series, self-study, covariance, arma

Consider the ARMA(2,1) time series
$$
x_t−0.1x_{t−1}−0.06x_{t−2}=w_t−0.5w_{t−1} ,
$$
where $w_t$ is white noise with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2_w$.
Find the expectation of
$$
(x_t−0.1x_{t−1}−0.06x_{t−2})x_{t−h}, \quad h=0,1,...
$$
and
$$
(w_t−0.5w_{t−1})x_{t−h}, \quad h=0,1,...
$$
and show how this can be used to formulate a difference equation to determine the covariance $γ(h)=E[x_{t+h}x_t]$.

I'm using the book 'Time Series Analysis and Its Applications' Third Edition by Shumway and Stoffer. But can't find the relevant examples to draw on.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please use the `self-study` tag.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry :)